# Copy table tag formatting to ul & li tags

Tags: html, css

add List Image and Background Image to `<li>` items...

CSS Code :-

```
.sidebarmenu ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: disc;
font:bold 14px Verdana;
width: 180px; /* Main Menu Item widths */
border: 2px solid skyblue;
}
.sidebarmenu ul li{
position: relative;

}
/* Top level menu links style */
.sidebarmenu ul li a{
display: list-item;
overflow: auto; /*force hasLayout in IE7 */
color: red;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 6px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #778;
border-right: 1px solid #778;
}
.sidebarmenu ul li a:link, .sidebarmenu ul li a:visited, .sidebarmenu ul li a:active{
 background-color: lightblue;/*background of tabs (default state)#012D58*/
}
.sidebarmenu ul li a:visited{
color: black;
}
.sidebarmenu ul li a:hover{
background-color: lightskyblue;
}
/*Sub level menu items */
.sidebarmenu ul li ul{
position: absolute;
width: 170px; /*Sub Menu Items width */
top: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
.sidebarmenu a.subfolderstyle{
background: url(images/right.gif) no-repeat 97% 50%;
}
```

HTML FORM:-

```
<body>
        <div class="sidebarmenu">
<ul id="sidebarmenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Add Location</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8084/FBS/add_Flat.jsp">Add Flat</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8084/FBS/add_Area.jsp">Add Area</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8084/FBS/logout.jsp">Log Out</a></li>

</ul>
        </div>
         </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all... your table structure and your ul-li structure is different:

- table cells are all on same level // li levels are different
- link names are different

i guess what you want to do is:

- set the "images/user_manager.jpg" Image to the `list-style-image`
- as we dont see the images and dont know what they are looking like i
  believe you want to set the "images/bg.jpg" Image as the
  `background-image` of the li-tags

in situations like that a screenshot or link would be nice.